# Difference between ul#someid and #someid ul

Tags: css, css-selectors

Simple question. What is the difference between `ul#someid` and `#someid ul`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one selects a `<ul>` element that has an `id` attribute of `someid`. The second one selects all `<ul>` elements that are inside of any element that has an `id` of `someid`. The space makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

The first is targetting a `ul` node with the id of `someid` and the second is targetting a `ul` which is anywhere in the children nodes of a node with id `someid`

The first pattern matches:

```
<ul id="someid">
   ...
</ul>
```

and the second pattern matches:

```
<div id="someid">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The second provided example is correct but don't forget you can have a grandchild `<ul>` and it will still match - meaning it is nested 2 levels deep.

Comment: @ProfileTwist This was only an example, and that point is covered in the explanation

Comment: Touche. Children nodes != grandchildren nodes to some people. I consider the same but its a common misconception on SO that I have started to notice.

Answer (score 2):

The former selector selects a `<ul>` that has the id `#someid` while the latter looks for an element with id `#someid` that has a `<ul>` as a descendant. The space is called a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#descendant-combinators)